# Native Script Grid Layout addChild from .ts file is working fine with android but in iOS it is not updating the view

Tags: nativescript

I am using the typescript code to add the FlexLayout in the GridLayout (that is already in view). In flexLayout I added an image to show it in the view. In android it is working fine but in iOS it is not updating the view. For see the image in iOS I have to swipe a screen slightly left to right. After swiping the screen image is displaying in iOS GridLayout view like android.

**Here is my typescript code for same:**

```
this.zone.run(() => {

    _that.imageArray.push(source);
    _that.rowPattern =  _that.getRowPattern(_that.imageArray.length);
    // to shift add button according to images.
    var layout = <GridLayout>_that.page.getViewById("container");
    let addButton = _that.page.getViewById("addButton");
    addButton.col = _that.imageArray.length % 2;
    addButton.row = Math.floor(_that.imageArray.length / 2);
    // create an stackLayout and image after that append it into view.
    let wrapper = new StackLayout();
    wrapper.className = 'image-wrapper';
    let index = _that.imageArray.length - 1;
    wrapper.row = Math.floor(index / 2);
    wrapper.col = index % 2;
    wrapper.width = _that.screenWidth / 2;
    wrapper.height = {unit: 'px', value: _that.screenWidth / 2};
    wrapper.backgroundColor = '#e1e1e2';
    wrapper.borderWidth = 5;
    wrapper.effectiveBorderBottomWidth = 7.5;
    wrapper.borderColor = 'white';
    wrapper.verticalAlignment = 'middle';
    // code to create an image.
    let image = new Image();
    image.className = 'images';
    image.src = source;
    _that.titleInfo = 'Angular';
    wrapper.addChild(image);
    layout.addChild(wrapper);
});
```

**HTML file for the view is:**

```
<ActionBar>
<NavigationButton text="" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" (tap)="backBtn()"></NavigationButton>
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal"
      ios:horizontalAlignment="center"
      android:horizontalAlignment="center">
      <Label text="{{titleInfo}}" class="main_header"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout ios:marginTop="20" width="100%" height="100%">
<FlexboxLayout height="10%" flexDirection="column" alignItems="center" justifyContent="flex-end">
    <Label class="title" text='Click on vehicle image to add photo'></Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
<ScrollView orientation="vertical" width="100%" height= "70%">
    <GridLayout class="images-wrapper" rows="{{rowPattern}}" columns ="*,*" id="container">

        <Image class="images addImage" id ="testIos" (tap)="addImage()"></Image>
        <FlexboxLayout class = "addButton-wrapper" width="{{screenWidth/2}}" height="{{screenWidth/2}}px" row="0" col="0" id="addButton">
            <Image class="images addImage" src = "res://vehiclebg" (tap)="addImage()"></Image>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
<FlexboxLayout  height="10%" width="100%">
</FlexboxLayout>
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center"  height="10%" width="100%">
    <Button text="Upload" class="upload-button" height="80%"></Button>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As image size is not specified initially it's height width is 0 and ios won't detect image load from url automatically.
You can provide specific height to image by default or you can use image caching.